# if title available print $title if disabled print somthing else

Tags: nodes

I use advanced forum but it uses default Drupal title method.

I know there is a module called [Comment subjects](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_subject) for this purpose but I need to do it in this way.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

```
 if $title >avalible print $title
 if $title disabled print <h3><a href="#<?php echo $comment->cid; ?>"> Re: <?php print $node->title ?></a></h3>
```

OR

```
 if > node print $node->title
 elseif comment $print <h3><a href="#<?php echo $comment->cid; ?>"> Re: <?php print $node->title ?></a></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the Solution.

Go to -> (advanced_forum/styles/naked/advanced-forum.naked.post.tpl.php)

```
  <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
    <div class="forum-post-title">
      <?php print $title ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Then replace it with:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
    <div class="forum-post-title">
        <?php print $title; ?>              
    </div>
<?php else: ?>      
    <div class="forum-comment-title">
        <h4><a href="#comment-<?php print $comment->cid; ?>"> Re : <?php print $node->title ?></a></h4>
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think you have a XSS vector in the title printing - it should be run through `check_plain()`. Personally I always try to avoid using a template if I can achieve the same effects by using a preprocess and modifying variables (which in this case is easily possible by modifying `$vars['title']`).

Answer (score 0):

When you disable the title tag does the node have value? Because if it does, all you need to do is adding an control statement.

```
if ($node->title[array values] == the disabled value) {
  // What I need to print here.
}
else {
  // Print the rest.
}
```